# "Exit point" in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, yield

What is the last executed function/method that can accept parsed data?

I'm writing a specific spider for parsing a backend. My idea is to:

- create a list of pages and to "yield" over them (done),
- create a public constants to hold parsed data,
- pass the public data to `Jinja2` and get an html file.

The structure:

```
scrapyspider/
├── myspider
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       └── the_spider.py
├── scrapy.cfg
└── template.html
```

All of my code is in `the_spider.py`, and I would like to know the last executed function to which I can pass parsed data from yielding/parsing? I keep getting lost in parallel executions of yield and callbacks.

If the answer is to pass each "page" to a pipeline, how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: one place where every item is waiting, something like that?

Comment: I have no idea where that is :/

Comment: I am asking you if that is what you need. Or I am not understanding your question, if you want to do something with every item use an items pipeline, if you want to execute something when the spider is about to close, use an extension with the spider_closed signal